# trying to sorting a listview by image index

Tags: delphi

I am trying to sort the items of a ListView by their image indexes.  So, if an item is set for image 4, it will stay in front of all other items.  I cannot seem to figure this out.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Show what you have, and ask for help.

Comment: how do you format code in messages in here?

Comment: I got the code from google search
http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2005/qt/qtsortlistview.htm

modified it a little to use imageindex but was no good

Comment: There is documentation when editing

Comment: Simon you need to post your modified code into your question or no one can help you.  Dont worry about formatting just paste it in.

Comment: @MsYvette nothing to with this question. Also I don't see a decision to your zero voted answer on meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Compare(Sender: TObject; Item1, Item2: TListItem;
  Data: Integer; var Compare: Integer);
begin
  if Item1.ImageIndex = 4 then
    Compare := -1 // Item1 should be first
  else if Item2.ImageIndex = 4 then
    Compare := 1 // Item2 should be first
  else
    Compare := 0; // the order doesn't matter
end;
```

That will put all of the items with ImageIndex 4 up front, but all of the items will have their natural ordering otherwise.

If you want more control over how image items are sorted in relation to each other, and how other items are sorted in relation to each other, you can expand the comparisons:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Compare(Sender: TObject; Item1, Item2: TListItem;
  Data: Integer; var Compare: Integer);
begin
  if Item1.ImageIndex = 4 then
  begin
    if Item2.ImageIndex = 4 then
    begin
      // two image items, do other comparisons here...
      Compare := ...;
    end else
    begin
      // image and non-image items, image item goes first...
      Compare := -1;
    end;
  end
  else if Item2.ImageIndex = 4 then
  begin
    // non-image and image items, image item goes first...
    Compare := 1;
  end else
  begin
    // two non-image items, do other comparisons here...
    Compare := ...;
  end;
end;
```